# Confirm and redirect to other view in JSF

Tags: jsf, seam

Is it possible to add a confirmation box to the following component (Seam button ) ?
I tried this ( see code below) : but when I click OK/Cancel nothing happens.
When I remove the `onclick` everything works normally but without a confirm.

Code:

```
<s:button value="Delete this"
          id="updateTM"
          view="/secure/CustomerDelete.xhtml"
          onclick="if (! confirm('Really start deletion of  this customers ?') ) { return false;}; return true; "
          action="#{customerHome.initAsyncProcess}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with this (same layout as Seam butons) :

```
<h:commandButton
    onclick="if (! confirm('Really want to do that?')) return false"
    value="Delete it"
    action="#{customerHome.startAsync}">
</h:commandButton>
```

Then in my bean I do the following :

```
public String startAsync(){
        this.initAsyncProcess();
        return "/secure/CustomerDuplicateDelete.xhtml";
}
```